# How do I add URP lighting reaction to the following handwritten shader?

Tags: unity, shaders

I'm on Unity. I'm not very experienced with shaders nor shader graphs, but I managed to get this one to work on URP. What it currently does is, it takes noise values, and creates a tileset out of them. Also it changes the Hue Saturation of this tile Set.

In terms of lighting, at the moment I'm changing the light intensity or brightness "manually" with the `_LightIntensity` variable. But this shader applied to a material in a quad is not being affected by URP 2D lights, like global, shape lights, unless they are volumetric.
When I place one of those 2D URP lights on top of the sprite in the scene, lights wont make brighter parts of the sprite.
Any way I can add to the code to make it affected by 2D lights?

```
Shader "Custom/URPTilemapLitHSV" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Map", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Tileset("Tileset", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Size("Map & Tileset Size", Vector) = (16, 16, 20, 13)
        _LightIntensity("Light Intensity", Range(0, 5)) = 1
        _HueShift("Hue Shift", Range(-180, 180)) = 0
        _Saturation("Saturation", Range(0, 2)) = 1
        _Brightness("Brightness", Range(0, 2)) = 1
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags {
            "RenderPipeline" = "UniversalPipeline"
            "Queue" = "Transparent"
        }
        LOD 200
        Pass {
            HLSLPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma target 3.0
            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/ShaderLibrary/Core.hlsl"
            sampler2D _MainTex;
            sampler2D _Tileset;
            sampler2D _LightTex;
            float4 _Size;
            float _HueShift;
            float _Saturation;
            float _Brightness;
            struct appdata {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };
            struct v2f {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };
            v2f vert(appdata v) {
                v2f o;
                o.uv = v.uv;
                o.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
                return o;
            }
            float3 RGBtoHSV(float3 color) {
                float3 hsv;
                float minVal = min(min(color.r, color.g), color.b);
                float maxVal = max(max(color.r, color.g), color.b);
                hsv.z = maxVal;
                float delta = maxVal - minVal;
                if (maxVal > 0.0) {
                    hsv.y = delta / maxVal;
                    if (color.r >= maxVal)
                        hsv.x = (color.g - color.b) / delta;
                    else if (color.g >= maxVal)
                        hsv.x = 2.0 + (color.b - color.r) / delta;
                    else
                        hsv.x = 4.0 + (color.r - color.g) / delta;
                    hsv.x *= 60.0;
                    if (hsv.x < 0.0)
                        hsv.x += 360.0;
                }
                else {
                    hsv.y = 0.0;
                    hsv.x = 0.0;
                }
                return hsv;
            }
            float3 HSVtoRGB(float3 hsv) {
                float3 rgb;
                if (hsv.y == 0.0) {
                    rgb = float3(hsv.z, hsv.z, hsv.z);
                }
                else {
                    float hue = hsv.x / 60.0;
                    int i = floor(hue);
                    float f = hue - i;
                    float p = hsv.z * (1.0 - hsv.y);
                    float q = hsv.z * (1.0 - hsv.y * f);
                    float t = hsv.z * (1.0 - hsv.y * (1.0 - f));
                    if (i == 0)
                        rgb = float3(hsv.z, t, p);
                    else if (i == 1)
                        rgb = float3(q, hsv.z, p);
                    else if (i == 2)
                        rgb = float3(p, hsv.z, t);
                    else if (i == 3)
                        rgb = float3(p, q, hsv.z);
                    else if (i == 4)
                        rgb = float3(t, p, hsv.z);
                    else
                        rgb = float3(hsv.z, p, q);
                }
                return rgb;
            }
            float4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target {
                float2 mapLocation = IN.uv * _Size.xy;
                float2 inTileUV = frac(mapLocation);
                mapLocation = (mapLocation - inTileUV) / _Size.xy;
                inTileUV = inTileUV * 1275.0f / 1280.0f + 1.0f / 1280.0f;
                float4 grad = float4(ddx(IN.uv), ddy(IN.uv));
                float4 tileIndex = tex2D(_MainTex, mapLocation);
                tileIndex = (tileIndex * 255.0f + inTileUV.xyxy) / _Size.zwzw;
                float4 over = tex2Dgrad(_Tileset, tileIndex.zw, grad.xy, grad.zw);
                float3 colorRGB = over.rgb;
                // Apply hue shift
                float3 colorHSV = RGBtoHSV(colorRGB);
                colorHSV.x += _HueShift;
                colorHSV.x = frac(colorHSV.x / 360.0) * 360.0;
                colorRGB = HSVtoRGB(colorHSV);
                // Apply saturation and brightness
                colorRGB = saturate(colorRGB * _Saturation) * _Brightness;
                float4 finalColor = float4(colorRGB, over.a);
                // Multiply by light intensity
               finalColor.rgb *= _LightIntensity;
                if (finalColor.a < 0.5)
                    discard;
                return finalColor;
            }
            ENDHLSL
        }
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

I looked into the URP sprite lit shader provided by Unity which is affected by 2D URP lights and it seems a very complex code can't seem to get any ideas from it. But ideally it would be used to modify the first shader provided.It seems to differentiate the type of light that is applied be URP global, shape etc...

This is the Unity sprite lit Shader

```
Shader "Universal Render Pipeline/2D/Sprite-Lit-Default"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Diffuse", 2D) = "white" {}
        _MaskTex("Mask", 2D) = "white" {}
        _NormalMap("Normal Map", 2D) = "bump" {}

        // Legacy properties. They're here so that materials using this shader can gracefully fallback to the legacy sprite shader.
        [HideInInspector] _Color("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        [HideInInspector] _RendererColor("RendererColor", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        [HideInInspector] _Flip("Flip", Vector) = (1,1,1,1)
        [HideInInspector] _AlphaTex("External Alpha", 2D) = "white" {}
        [HideInInspector] _EnableExternalAlpha("Enable External Alpha", Float) = 0
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags {"Queue" = "Transparent" "RenderType" = "Transparent" "RenderPipeline" = "UniversalPipeline" }

        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha, One OneMinusSrcAlpha
        Cull Off
        ZWrite Off

        Pass
        {
            Tags { "LightMode" = "Universal2D" }

            HLSLPROGRAM
            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/ShaderLibrary/Core.hlsl"

            #pragma vertex CombinedShapeLightVertex
            #pragma fragment CombinedShapeLightFragment

            #pragma multi_compile USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_0 __
            #pragma multi_compile USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_1 __
            #pragma multi_compile USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_2 __
            #pragma multi_compile USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_3 __
            #pragma multi_compile _ DEBUG_DISPLAY

            struct Attributes
            {
                float3 positionOS   : POSITION;
                float4 color        : COLOR;
                float2  uv          : TEXCOORD0;
                UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
            };

            struct Varyings
            {
                float4  positionCS  : SV_POSITION;
                half4   color       : COLOR;
                float2  uv          : TEXCOORD0;
                half2   lightingUV  : TEXCOORD1;
                #if defined(DEBUG_DISPLAY)
                float3  positionWS  : TEXCOORD2;
                #endif
                UNITY_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO
            };

            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/2D/Include/LightingUtility.hlsl"

            TEXTURE2D(_MainTex);
            SAMPLER(sampler_MainTex);
            TEXTURE2D(_MaskTex);
            SAMPLER(sampler_MaskTex);
            half4 _MainTex_ST;
            float4 _Color;
            half4 _RendererColor;

            #if USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_0
            SHAPE_LIGHT(0)
            #endif

            #if USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_1
            SHAPE_LIGHT(1)
            #endif

            #if USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_2
            SHAPE_LIGHT(2)
            #endif

            #if USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_3
            SHAPE_LIGHT(3)
            #endif

            Varyings CombinedShapeLightVertex(Attributes v)
            {
                Varyings o = (Varyings)0;
                UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(v);
                UNITY_INITIALIZE_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO(o);

                o.positionCS = TransformObjectToHClip(v.positionOS);
                #if defined(DEBUG_DISPLAY)
                o.positionWS = TransformObjectToWorld(v.positionOS);
                #endif
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                o.lightingUV = half2(ComputeScreenPos(o.positionCS / o.positionCS.w).xy);

                o.color = v.color * _Color * _RendererColor;
                return o;
            }

            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/2D/Include/CombinedShapeLightShared.hlsl"

            half4 CombinedShapeLightFragment(Varyings i) : SV_Target
            {
                const half4 main = i.color * SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_MainTex, sampler_MainTex, i.uv);
                const half4 mask = SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_MaskTex, sampler_MaskTex, i.uv);
                SurfaceData2D surfaceData;
                InputData2D inputData;

                InitializeSurfaceData(main.rgb, main.a, mask, surfaceData);
                InitializeInputData(i.uv, i.lightingUV, inputData);

                return CombinedShapeLightShared(surfaceData, inputData);
            }
            ENDHLSL
        }

        Pass
        {
            Tags { "LightMode" = "NormalsRendering"}

            HLSLPROGRAM
            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/ShaderLibrary/Core.hlsl"

            #pragma vertex NormalsRenderingVertex
            #pragma fragment NormalsRenderingFragment

            struct Attributes
            {
                float3 positionOS   : POSITION;
                float4 color        : COLOR;
                float2 uv           : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 tangent      : TANGENT;
                UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
            };

            struct Varyings
            {
                float4  positionCS      : SV_POSITION;
                half4   color           : COLOR;
                float2  uv              : TEXCOORD0;
                half3   normalWS        : TEXCOORD1;
                half3   tangentWS       : TEXCOORD2;
                half3   bitangentWS     : TEXCOORD3;
                UNITY_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO
            };

            TEXTURE2D(_MainTex);
            SAMPLER(sampler_MainTex);
            TEXTURE2D(_NormalMap);
            SAMPLER(sampler_NormalMap);
            half4 _NormalMap_ST;  // Is this the right way to do this?

            Varyings NormalsRenderingVertex(Attributes attributes)
            {
                Varyings o = (Varyings)0;
                UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(attributes);
                UNITY_INITIALIZE_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO(o);

                o.positionCS = TransformObjectToHClip(attributes.positionOS);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(attributes.uv, _NormalMap);
                o.color = attributes.color;
                o.normalWS = -GetViewForwardDir();
                o.tangentWS = TransformObjectToWorldDir(attributes.tangent.xyz);
                o.bitangentWS = cross(o.normalWS, o.tangentWS) * attributes.tangent.w;
                return o;
            }

            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/2D/Include/NormalsRenderingShared.hlsl"

            half4 NormalsRenderingFragment(Varyings i) : SV_Target
            {
                const half4 mainTex = i.color * SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_MainTex, sampler_MainTex, i.uv);
                const half3 normalTS = UnpackNormal(SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_NormalMap, sampler_NormalMap, i.uv));

                return NormalsRenderingShared(mainTex, normalTS, i.tangentWS.xyz, i.bitangentWS.xyz, i.normalWS.xyz);
            }
            ENDHLSL
        }

        Pass
        {
            Tags { "LightMode" = "UniversalForward" "Queue"="Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent"}

            HLSLPROGRAM
            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/ShaderLibrary/Core.hlsl"

            #pragma vertex UnlitVertex
            #pragma fragment UnlitFragment

            struct Attributes
            {
                float3 positionOS   : POSITION;
                float4 color        : COLOR;
                float2 uv           : TEXCOORD0;
                UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
            };

            struct Varyings
            {
                float4  positionCS      : SV_POSITION;
                float4  color           : COLOR;
                float2  uv              : TEXCOORD0;
                #if defined(DEBUG_DISPLAY)
                float3  positionWS  : TEXCOORD2;
                #endif
                UNITY_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO
            };

            TEXTURE2D(_MainTex);
            SAMPLER(sampler_MainTex);
            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            float4 _Color;
            half4 _RendererColor;

            Varyings UnlitVertex(Attributes attributes)
            {
                Varyings o = (Varyings)0;
                UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(attributes);
                UNITY_INITIALIZE_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO(o);

                o.positionCS = TransformObjectToHClip(attributes.positionOS);
                #if defined(DEBUG_DISPLAY)
                o.positionWS = TransformObjectToWorld(v.positionOS);
                #endif
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(attributes.uv, _MainTex);
                o.color = attributes.color * _Color * _RendererColor;
                return o;
            }

            float4 UnlitFragment(Varyings i) : SV_Target
            {
                float4 mainTex = i.color * SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_MainTex, sampler_MainTex, i.uv);

                #if defined(DEBUG_DISPLAY)
                SurfaceData2D surfaceData;
                InputData2D inputData;
                half4 debugColor = 0;

                InitializeSurfaceData(mainTex.rgb, mainTex.a, surfaceData);
                InitializeInputData(i.uv, inputData);
                SETUP_DEBUG_DATA_2D(inputData, i.positionWS);

                if(CanDebugOverrideOutputColor(surfaceData, inputData, debugColor))
                {
                    return debugColor;
                }
                #endif

                return mainTex;
            }
            ENDHLSL
        }
    }

    Fallback "Sprites/Default"
}
```

Comment: "I looked into the URP sprite lit shader and it seems a very complex code" well, I can tell you that complex code isn't there just for decoration. The code in the sprite lit shader is the code that needs to be there for sprite lighting. If there were a way to do it without that code, that's what the developers would have preferred and done instead. Have you encountered a specific obstacle in adapting this code that we can help you overcome?

Comment: I tried to do this at the end finalColor.rgb *= tex2D(_LightingTex, IN.uv).rgb; but it wont change the ouput at all

Comment: @DMGregory can I just make calls to that code of spriteLitURP instead of rewritting it in my custom shader? it seems like in the original spriteLitURP shader the shader is looking at the type of light that hits the shader, be global, custom shape , spot...

Comment: You may find it easier to start by copying the standard shader, then adding your own logic and customisations on top of it.

Comment: When you created this shader, did you not create it using the sprite lit/surface shader template?

Comment: I used a shader created based on the builtin render pipeline that will map the uv coordinates, then translated it to urp, but lost the lighting in the process